# BadArgument and JSON parsing error when making an API call

Tags: ajax, api, azure, react-native, fetch-api

Inside my component, I'm trying to make an api call using fetch.

The API takes in an image `.jpg` file path as such - `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E1E919E-6C21-4CC7-B9C2-5B4B3BC84B0F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540chuks93%252Fihu-main/Camera/F3B8EBCC-BB09-4603-AF7E-FD3CA792C237.jpg` and it should return a `JSON` object.

Here's my fetch call below:

```
export default  {

processImage: (image) => {
// Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
var subscriptionKey = "*******************";

var uriBase = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

// Display the image.
    var sourceImageUrl = image;
console.log(typeof sourceImageUrl)
console.log("here", sourceImageUrl);

// Perform the REST API call.
return fetch(uriBase, {

        method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey
    },

    body: JSON.stringify(sourceImageUrl),
    })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then(function (data){
        console.log("hello", data);
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

  }
}
```

When I run the above code this is the error it returns:

`Object {
  "error": Object {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "JSON parsing error.",
  }`

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
    body: JSON.stringify(sourceImageUrl),
```

to

```
    body: JSON.stringify({url: sourceImageUrl}),
```

to make the body of the post a proper json object.

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked!!! but now I have another problem: the photo file created by the expo camera returns an error. `Object {
  "error": Object {
    "code": "InvalidURL",
    "message": "Invalid image URL.",
  }`  the expo camera creates this: `"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E1E919E-6C21-4CC7-B9C2-5B4B3BC84B0F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540chuks93%252Fihu-main/Camera/E67E8249-2B53-49EA-B51D-42CD98768634.jpg"` but that returns the error but any image address from any most images will work fine.

Comment: I think you'll find the images that work have network URLs like https://... but that file:/// urls will not work... azure has no way to load files local to your computer.  You'll need to put your images somewhere you can serve them with http:// urls.  I haven't looked at the API but maybe there is a way to inline the image as part of the payload instead of just a url.